# Inconsistency among hash codes returned from shared static field

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a simple app that captures push notifications sent from firebase cloud messaging and stores them into an built-in inbox.

- The `InboxController` handles the logic for storing each notification.
- The `backgroundMessageReceived` is self explanatory.
- The `backgroundMessageTapped` is self explanatory.

Only a single instance of `InboxController` is allowed to exist. Therefore, a singleton pattern is enforced with a static field as the only available reference to such a controller.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> backgroundMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
  final inboxController = InboxController.getInstance();
  print('InboxController2: ${inboxController.hashCode}');

  return Future<void>.value();
}

void backgroundMessageTapped(RemoteMessage message) {
  final inboxController = InboxController.getInstance();
  print('InboxController3: ${inboxController.hashCode}');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final fba = await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundMessageReceived);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(backgroundMessageTapped);

  const project = MaterialApp(
    home: InboxScreen(),
  );

  runApp(project);
}

class InboxController {
  InboxController._();

  static InboxController? _instance;
  factory InboxController.getInstance() {
    return _instance ??= InboxController._();
  }
}

class InboxScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const InboxScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<InboxScreen> createState() {
    return _InboxScreenState();
  }
}

class _InboxScreenState extends State<InboxScreen> {
  InboxController? inboxController;

  void assignInitValues() {
    inboxController = InboxController.getInstance();
    print('InboxController1: ${inboxController.hashCode}');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    assignInitValues();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Placeholder(),
    );
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
InboxController1: 476298463
InboxController2: 476298463
InboxController3: 476298463
```

Actual output:

```
InboxController1: 476298463
InboxController2: 650985069
InboxController3: 476298463
```

However, there seems to be an unexpected behavior when the firebase cloud messaging library calls `backgroundMessageReceived`. As you can see, the reference hash code associated with `InboxController.getInstance` is not the same on every call.

This behavior suggests that 2 instances of `InboxController` are being created. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but your initState is wrong.  super should always come first.

Comment: Oh, and is there a chance that the background message handler is running in a separate isolate?  If so, yes, it **will** have a different hashcode.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz If so, how can they both be running on the same isolate? After all, it is important that when a background message is received, it will then be store in the inbox.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz is it possible to pass data between isolates or threads in flutter?

Comment: Yes.  See SendPort and RecievePort.  Beware: it's not simple or universal.  Share-nothing isolates solve many problems, but introduce others.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz However, there is another problem. The firebase cloud messaging library is the original caller of the registered function for receiving messages in a different isolate. I have no access to the isolate being used by the library. So, how can I possibly apply the Send/ReceivePort solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You can copy this source code & paste it into the `main.dart` file and run it. Don't forget to look at the attached output below the source code.

```
import "dart:developer";

import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const MainScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                // Press this button to call backgroundMessageReceived function
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: function1, child: Text("1")),
                ),
                // Press this button to call backgroundMessageTapped function
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: function2, child: Text("2")),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // Your StatefulWidget Inbox class
            Expanded(child: InboxScreen()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Singleton controller class
class InboxController {
  InboxController._();
  static final InboxController instance = InboxController._();
}

// StatefulWidget Inbox class
class InboxScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const InboxScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<InboxScreen> createState() => _InboxScreenState();
}

class _InboxScreenState extends State<InboxScreen> {
  final InboxController inboxController = InboxController.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    log("InboxController1: ${inboxController.hashCode}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

// Your backgroundMessageReceived function
Future<void> function1() async {
  final InboxController inboxController = InboxController.instance;
  log("InboxController2: ${inboxController.hashCode}");
  return;
}

// Your backgroundMessageTapped function
Future<void> function2() async {
  final InboxController inboxController = InboxController.instance;
  log("InboxController3: ${inboxController.hashCode}");
  return;
}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: This answer would be better if it weren't a code-only answer and additionally provided some explanation for what was fixed and why.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here. If you call the functions for receiving messages manually via a graphical user interface or via the main function, everything works fine. However, the problem is when the firebase cloud messaging library calls the same function.

Comment: It is important that the firebase cloud messaging library calls the function registered for receiving messages and this is where the problem occurs. There seems to be the case that the library which is the original caller of the function for receiving messages is running in a different isolate or thread.

Comment: I can understand. Could you try and test it? If you already did, then what's the result?

Comment: All you need to do is to change the function name and add params.